# ngOptions bind variable linked to option selection

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of countries `$scope.countries` with this format:
`[{Name: "Afghanistan", Code: "AF"}, {Name: "Åland Islands", Code: "AX"}, ...]`. 
In my JS, I also have an undefined variable `$scope.selectedCountry = {};`. I want to display a select menu of country names to the user using the ngOptions directive and then bind the code of the country the user has selected to `selectedCountry`. Currently I display my select using this Jade code:

```
 select(required, ng-model="selectedCountry",
 ng-options="country.Name for country in countries")
```

How can I bind country.Code instead of country.Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-options` uses the form: [model value] as [display text] for [item in collection] in [collection], so:

```
ng-options="country.Code as country.Name for country in countries"
```